# Fix Java Imports in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

What is the best way to do this?
My understanding is I need to search all of these, go find the jars, download them, and then add them to the class path. Is that it?
In the past when I used eclipse it would add them automatically when clicking on the red Xs and selecting fix import.
Am I missing something?
[image]

Comment: You can manage dependencies with gradle or maven.

Comment: Nowadays, adding JARs to the classpath might not be enough. There might be a `module-info.java` file that needs to be edited or conflict caused by a same named package in two modules, which is not allowed since Java 9. Please show the error messages and the content of `module-info.java`, if it exists.

Comment: @howlger not familiar with that file or where it's at , provide more details if you like. It's already a maven project. ??

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Let's say I've never seen that or used it. How does one go about seeing it and using it?

Comment: @user2568374 I'm not a gradle user, so I can't say much about it, but [this](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html) gives a quick overview of maven and [this](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Converting_Eclipse_Java_Project_to_Maven_Project) link about maven in eclipse shold help) helps converting an eclipse project to a maven project.

Comment: `module-info.java`, if it exists, is in the default package (see [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform_Module_System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform_Module_System)). Please show the error messages.

Comment: @howlger the error messages are in the screen shot JSONParser not resolving was one. I. just searched the packages and added the jars, very cumbersome without maven. This was a small project so I didn't want to do al that.

Answer (score 0):

After reading responses and working on my own , I found the answer was just search the classes, download the jars and add them to external libraries section of build path.